# How to fix "Unable to find command: live-update" in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm trying to add live-update to my ionic app by running:

```
ionic live-update add \
--app-id="my-app-id" \
--channel-name="Production" \
--update-method="auto"
```

is failing with:

```
[ERROR] Unable to find command: live-update add
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Command `ionic deploy` was changed to `ionic live-update` in ionic CLI 7.

To fix this, either update your ionic CLI to version 7+, or write the command as follows:

```
ionic deploy add \
--app-id="my-app-id" \
--channel-name="Production" \
--update-method="auto"
```